# Angular5 router appends component instead of replacing it

Tags: angular

I have the routing set up as follows in my `app.module.ts`:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: 'home', component: AppComponent},
    {path: 'articles', component: ArticlesComponent},
    {path: 'portfolio', component: PortfolioComponent},
    {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
    {path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent}
]

@NgModule({
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ArticlesComponent,
    PortfolioComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    ContactComponent
],
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: false })
]
```

And my `app.component.html` as :

```
<a routerLink="/home">HOME</a>
<a routerLink="/articles">ARTICLES</a>
<a routerLink="/portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a>
<a routerLink="/about">ABOUT</a>
<a routerLink="/contact">CONTACT</a
```

I have the `<router-outlet>` in my `app.component.html` too, however, when I click on the component I would like to go on, it doesn't replace the component on screen it shows up at the bottom of my homepage.

I have taken the `BrowserAnimationsModule` and `NoopAnimationModule` out of my `App.Module.ts` as it worked for someone else, however, the same issue is coming on for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think it was just a bug in the server or with angular, as I have tried it this morning and it seems to be working as normal.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a routeroutlet in the host view's HTML. After that one, it loads the pages then: 
`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. 
Could also be that you have it in the wrong place.

Comment: I have it in my app.component.html, at the bottom of my navbar code